# How to limit the upload/download of a program already running (A process)?

Tags: linux, bandwidth

I have already tried trickle and wondershaper.

I need a program that can limit the speed of download/upload of an already running program. Similar to the how NetLimiter in Windows limits already running processes.

I am using Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [pyshaper](http://freenet.mcnabhosting.com/python/pyshaper/) to download, and an install tutorial [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=993210).

Comment: Thank you but it did not work. It did not specify a process but instead only an network interface or ports.

Comment: I don't run linux, but it seems to be that "pid of locally connected program" is one of the criteria you can use to select a program...

Comment: It show that option in the webpage but it does not appear implemented.

Comment: the [man page](http://www.freenet.org.nz/python/pyshaper/pyshaper.html) also shows a way to do it... what does running the suggested command do (example shown [here](http://www.freenet.org.nz/python/man8/pyshaper.conf.8.html))

Comment: Does not do anything. I already tried the way the man page said. It loads the service and then i load the program. If i change anything it does not work. The option of pid like i said is not implemented.

Comment: [here](http://rbytes.net/linux/pyshaper-review/) its mentioned as a key feature, but I guess its possible its not implemented.

Comment: What amazes me is how tough it is to find one. i mean windows has several like the netlimiter and mentioned. But Linux, an operating system that is an expert in networks does not even have a tool to easily limit (Something that should be very easy to do in linux) the bandwidth of not only an interface like the above mention programs i tried but to limit how a process uses the bandwidth. This option that i thought to be a part of the way the network in Linux is made is not found. So my best bet is that the option i have not found it yet or it does not exist....yet